# Retrieve records that have expired using the where clause in MySQL and different columns by date and time

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Here is my current mysql table

| id | Name | expiry_date | expiry_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sample1 | 09-01-2023 | 11:00 AM |
| 2 | Sample2 | 09-01-2023 | 3:00 PM |
| 3 | Sample3 | 08-01-2023 | 10:00 PM |

Query:

```
select * 
from table 
where STR_TO_DATE(table.expiry_date, '%d-%m-%Y') < '2023-01-09' 
   OR (DATE_FORMAT(concat(table.expiry_date,' ',table.expiry_time),'%d-%m-%Y %g:%i %A') <= NOW()))
```

I also wish to obtain the records that are out-of-date as of the present time.

How to do that?

Comment: *Here is my current mysql table* Provide it as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO.

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE STR_TO_DATE(expiry_date, '%d-%m-%Y') < '2023-01-09' OR (DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(expiry_date,' ',expiry_time),'%d-%m-%Y %h:%i %p') <= NOW());

Comment: Added the table name before the expiry_date and expiry_time columns in the STR_TO_DATE and DATE_FORMAT functions

Comment: Why separate the date and time columns? MySQL has a perfectly usable [`DATETIME` data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html)

Comment: Corrected the %g format specifier to %h in the DATE_FORMAT function. %g is used for hours in the 12-hour clock format, but the time in the expiry_time column appears to be in the 24-hour clock format.

Comment: Corrected the %A format specifier to %p in the DATE_FORMAT function. %A is used for the full-day name (e.g. "Monday"), but %p is used for the AM/PM indicator.

Comment: @TahaFarooqui 3:00 PM is definitely _not_ in 24-hour time format

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE (STR_TO_DATE(expiry_date, '%d-%m-%Y') < NOW() AND column1 = 'some value') OR (DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(expiry_date,' ',expiry_time),'%d-%m-%Y %h:%i %p') <= NOW() AND column2 = 'some other value');

Comment: Its retrieves current date records but with future time also showing. Future time records should not show

Comment: Did you try to replace '%d-%m-%Y' = '2023-01-09' to '%d-%m-%Y' = '09-01-23'

Comment: "Warning: #1292 Incorrect datetime value" is showing

Comment: what data type did you set for expiry_date and expiry_time?

Comment: why didn't you set expiry_date and expiry_time in one column? For example, column name expiry and data type should be (DateTime Or timestamp). So, it would become easier for you to get the exact result easily. Example: https://prnt.sc/B0sjtcN5xS-Q

Comment: varchar datatypes are used for expiry date and expiry time.

Comment: I have changed the time format to 13:00:00 (HH:mm:ss).
And my query like "SELECT * FROM table WHERE STR_TO_DATE(expiry_date, '%d-%m-%Y') < NOW() AND (STR_TO_DATE(concat(expiry_date,' ',expiry_time),'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') <= NOW());"
This resolved my problem; grateful

Answer (score 0):

You can use `STR_TO_DATE` to convert your varchar date as follows :

```
select *
from _table
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(concat(_table.expiry_date,' ',_table.expiry_time), '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i %p') <= now();
```

you can check it here : https://dbfiddle.uk/emR4cg3s